# Libraries must use same version error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library

I am getting this error whenever I add the Glide library to the `app.gradle` and I can't get rid of it.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

The build file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.david.six_month"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your project level `build.gradle` file it will force all android support library to use the same version

```
allprojects {
    ...

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                details.useVersion 'your library version here'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Glide is using a newer version of a support library. You can either bump the rest of your support libraries to use the newest version as well, or if for other reasons you cannot do that, exclude the support library from the Glide library like this:

```
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was about to bash my head to the walls. All my libs are 26 except the newest glide and i was getting error and mixed support libs inside gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a section defining the configuration to force a specific implementation of a library which needs to be used. For example,

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your error for example :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)

*The solution is to compile the versions of these libraries like that :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
```

-if another library had the same issue and had another version just compile it with your support:appcompat version

This resolved my problem and I hope it resolves yours.

Best wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

Then I added the **Design** dependency in `build.gradle - Module:app` and it solved the problem:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error because of Glide library.Try picasso image loader or other image loaders